# vlcj Error handling

Tags: java, javafx, vlcj

I'm working on a selfmade video-media-player in JavaFX and therefore I'm using vlcj. I'm using a DirectMediaPlayerComponent which renders the video to a canvas. Everthing fine up to here. The video plays smooth and also the controlls are working.

However, sometimes i get a lot of RuntimeErrors which cause the canvas to turn black but the sound is still played, for example

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image dimensions must be > 0
at com.sun.prism.Image.<init>(Image.java:271)
at com.sun.prism.Image.<init>(Image.java:241)
at com.sun.prism.Image.fromByteBgraPreData(Image.java:79)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderStream(NGCanvas.java:591)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

or

```
java.lang.InternalError: Unrecognized PGCanvas token: -128
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderStream(NGCanvas.java:780)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The errors occure very unpredictable, it does not depend on the video or the videoformat,
i tested with several different files.

My question is, how can i catch this errors and implement a recovery strategy. I have tried to override the error method of 'MediaPlayerEventListener'

```
public void error(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
```

but seems to have no effect.

EDIT: This is the code I'm using:

```
mediaPlayerComponent = new TestMediaPlayerComponent();
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(VIDEO_FILE);

private class TestMediaPlayerComponent extends DirectMediaPlayerComponent {

    @Override
    public void display(DirectMediaPlayer mediaPlayer, Memory[] nativeBuffers, BufferFormat bufferFormat) {
        Memory nativeBuffer = nativeBuffers[0];
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = nativeBuffer.getByteBuffer(0, nativeBuffer.size());
        pixelWriter.setPixels(0, 0, bufferFormat.getWidth(), bufferFormat.getHeight(), pixelFormat, byteBuffer, bufferFormat.getPitches()[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        System.out.println("Error detected!");
    }

    public TestMediaPlayerComponent() {
        super(new TestBufferFormatCallback());
    }
}

private class TestBufferFormatCallback implements BufferFormatCallback {

    @Override
    public BufferFormat getBufferFormat(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight) {
        int width = (int) stackPane.getWidth();
        int height = (int) stackPane.getHeight();

        Double ratio = stackPane.getWidth()/stackPane.getHeight();
        Double sourceRatio = Double.valueOf(sourceWidth)/Double.valueOf(sourceHeight);

        if(ratio <= sourceRatio) {
            height = (int)  (width/sourceRatio);
        } else {
            width = (int) (height * sourceRatio);
        }

        canvas.setWidth(width);
        canvas.setHeight(height);
        anchorPane.setPrefWidth(width);
        anchorPane.setPrefHeight(height); 

        return new RV32BufferFormat(width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post a full stack-trace to understand the root cause of the NullPointerException - it's impossible to help you given the information you've posted.

Comment: The stack trace is always differnt depending on the error. It repeats the same error over and over, sarting with the lines i posted.

Comment: Without code, or a full stack-trace, it's pretty much impossible to help. vlcj JavaFX video applications can play just fine for many hours if implemented correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my question and posted the code I'm using and the complete output I get. However these are just two errors off the many that may occure. But I can't reconstruct them.

Comment: In your display() callback it would be interesting to know the values of nativeBuffer.size() and bufferFormat.getWidth() and bufferFormat.getHeight() when it fails. Maybe you found a race condition, but it's really hard to say.

Comment: I habe checked the output of the methodes you said but it stays the same when the errors occure.
For my specific files it `nativeBuffer.size() = 2918416` `bufferFomat().getWidth() = 1140` and `bufferFormat.getHeight() = 640`

Comment: Did you find any solution here? I am in the same situation as you, the stream is somehow throwing a silent error and the player stops. I did not find yet any way to recover after this.